# Term aggregation on ElasticSearch join

Tags: elasticsearch, search, parent-child

I would like to perform an aggregation on a join relation using ElasticSearch 7.7.

I need to know how many children I have for each parent.
The only way that I found to solve my issue is to use script inside term aggregation, but my concern is about performance.

```
/my_index/_search
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "total": {
     "terms": {
       "script": {
         "lang": "painless",
         "source": "params['_source']['my_join']['parent']"
       }
     }
   },
   "max_total": {
     "max_bucket": {
       "buckets_path": "total>_count"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Someone knows a more fast way to execute this aggregation avoiding the script?

If the join field wasn't a parent/child I could replace the term aggregation with:

`"terms": { "field": "my_field" }`

To give more context I add some information about mapping:

I'm using Elastic 7.7.

I also attach a mapping with some sample documents:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_join": {
        "relations": {
          "other": "doc"
        },
        "type": "join"
      },
      "reader": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT example/_doc/1
{
  "reader": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ],
  "my_join": {
    "name": "other"
  }
} 

PUT example/_doc/2
{
  "reader": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ],
  "my_join": {
    "name": "other"
  }
} 

PUT example/_doc/3
{
  "content": "abc",
  "my_join": {
    "name": "doc",
    "parent": 1
  }
} 

PUT example/_doc/4
{
  "content": "def",
  "my_join": {
    "name": "doc"
    "parent": 2
  }
} 

PUT example/_doc/5
{
  "content": "def",
  "acl_join": {
    "name": "doc"
    "parent": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some sample doc,. mapping of the fields, elastic version?

Comment: I'm using Elastic 7.7

Comment: Thanks, could you please add sample data?

Comment: just edit the question. Thanks!